# Clarifying the role of symmetry in operator/state transformation rules

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, spacetime, symmetry

In Chapter 3 of his fairly classic text on quantum mechanics, Ballentine talks about the relationship between symmetries of physical space and corresponding transformations (via unitary operators, per Wigner's theorem) of Hilbert space. The discussion follows that in T. F. Jordan (1969) and (1975), which I think gives the (original?) classic discussion of constructing observables from consideration of spacetime symmetries.

Let's take the passive view of transformations throughout. Also, I will suppose for simplicity (and since that's all I know) that the Galilean transformations are the correct transformations between inertial reference frames. Also, I will refer to real/physical space as $V$, and Hilbert space as $\mathcal{H}$.

I am trying to parse/distinguish the consequences of (1) the correspondence (homomorphism?) between transformations between arbitrary reference frames for $V$, and unitary operators on $\mathcal{H}$ and (2) when those transformations are in particular spacetime symmetries (Galilean transformations) so that this is a transformation between inertial reference frames. I'll call transformations as in (1) $T$ and in (2) $\tau$.

The confusion abounds because Ballentine seems to imply that only for transformations $\tau$ should there be a unitary operator $U(\tau)$ on $\mathcal{H}$ which obeys the requirements

(A) $\langle \psi| U^{\dagger}(\tau)U(\tau)|\chi \rangle$ for all kets,

(B) Any observable $A$  gets mapped to some new observable $U(\tau)AU^{\dagger}(\tau)$,

such that the "physics is the same" in both frames.

My question is thus what can/do we say about the more general transformation $T$. If we transform to a new reference frame (noninertial) with $T$, is there no corresponding $U(T)$ or something like that?